# Pandas pick a nested column and plot it

Tags: python, pandas

I have a dataframe which kind of looks like this

```
 Category A            CategoryB
 Thing1 Thing2 Thing3  Thing1 Thing2 Thing3
0  x      x      x     x      x      x
1  x      x      x     x      x      x
2  x      x      x     x      x      x
```

I'm trying something like `df.plot(x='A.Thing1', y='A.Thing2')` but of course that's not working.

Comment: Used to face the same issue. Try this: https://kanoki.org/2019/07/24/how-to-create-pandas-pivot-table-and-crosstab/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can pass MultiIndex columns as tuples to `DataFrame.plot`:

**Example**

```
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt    

# Setup
midx = pd.MultiIndex.from_product([['Category A', 'Category B'],
                                   ['Thing 1', 'Thing 2']])

np.random.seed(0)
df = pd.DataFrame(np.random.randn(10, 4), columns=midx)
print(df)

  Category A           Category B          
     Thing 1   Thing 2    Thing 1   Thing 2
0   1.764052  0.400157   0.978738  2.240893
1   1.867558 -0.977278   0.950088 -0.151357
2  -0.103219  0.410599   0.144044  1.454274
3   0.761038  0.121675   0.443863  0.333674
4   1.494079 -0.205158   0.313068 -0.854096
5  -2.552990  0.653619   0.864436 -0.742165
6   2.269755 -1.454366   0.045759 -0.187184
7   1.532779  1.469359   0.154947  0.378163
8  -0.887786 -1.980796  -0.347912  0.156349
9   1.230291  1.202380  -0.387327 -0.302303
```

---

```
df.plot(x=('Category A', 'Thing 1'),
        y=('Category B', 'Thing 2'),
        kind='scatter')
```

[out]

[image]